# using jQuery's delegated event on() within every turbolinks page:load

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-events, turbolinks

I had this code in my rails app:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  myCustomFunction("#link-selector");
}

function myCustomFunction(linkCssSelector){
  // some stuff...

  $(document).on('click', linkCssSelector, function(){ 
    // ...some other stuff...
  });
}
```

The `click` event handling is already delegated to the **document**, but now I have to add **Turbolinks** to my app.

Then, I would take of the `ready()` function and do the following (based on my searches):

```
$(document).on("ready page:load", function() {
  myCustomFunction("#link-selector");
}
```

But some references tell me not to add bindings inside the page load, for it would create another binding for each time turbolinks loads something. That's pretty reasonable. But, in my case, I'm already delegating the **click** event to `document` inside `myCustomFuntion`.

The question is: can I run this event delegation `on()` function every time the page loads without problems?

**Obs**: Question could also be rephrased: Will this code cause trouble in the long run, after many page loads?

**Obs**2: I can't take the **click** event handling from inside `myCustomFunction`, because it depends on the calculations done before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding event handlers to the document on document `page:load` will as you have read create duplicate handlers. Try running the snipped below:

(click *Trigger page:load* several times before *Click me!*)

```js
$(document).on('page:load', function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#test', function(){
      $("#log").append('<li>clicked!</li>');
    });
});
$("#page_load").on('click', function(){
  $(document).trigger('page:load');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="page_load">Trigger page:load</button>
<button id="test">Click me!</button>
<ul id="log"></ul>
```

Turbolinks basically works by loading pages via Ajax instead and replacing the document contents.

It does try to clean up event handlers when it removes the old page from the DOM - but since your handler is bound to the document it is not removed.

You can relatively safely apply handlers to DOM elements such as the `body` instead since turbolinks guts out the document and replaces the contents.

Comment: I'll try delegating the handler to other elements. But turbolinks acts in mysterious ways. I'm beginning to think whether the design change I'm making to include it is worth it. Thanks for your answer.