# Ajax events not fired form_for

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a little issue with events in JS for a form in Rails.
In fact I done a form, but events are not fired when the form is submitted, I don't understand what I did wrong :/

Here is my form:

```
<%= form_for(@server, remote: true, method: "get", url: "/servers", html: { id: "edit_server_form" }) do |f| %>
Name: <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

And my JS:

```
edit_server_form = $("#edit_server_form")
edit_server_form.bind 'ajax:before', (e) ->
    console.log 'ajax:before'
edit_server_form.bind 'ajax:success', (event, data, status, xhr) ->
    console.log 'ajax:success'
edit_server_form.bind 'ajax:failure', (xhr, status, error) ->
    console.log 'ajax:failure'
edit_server_form.bind 'ajax:error', (xhr, status, error) ->
    console.log 'ajax:error'
edit_server_form.bind 'ajax:complete', ->
    console.log 'ajax:complete'
```

None of these events is triggered but the query is sent :/

[image: Screen Query sent]

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Where is the 'beginning', console log coming from? Because, as per the bind, it should say 'ajax:before' right? And do you have turbolinks enabled in your rails app?

Comment: In fact it's just a console.log at the begining to test file

Answer (score 0):

This *looks* like it could be to do with your [JQuery delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events):

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("ajax:before", "#edit_server_form", (e) ->
    console.log 'ajax:before'
).on("ajax:success", "#edit_server_form", (event, data, status, xhr) ->
    console.log 'ajax:success'
).on("ajax:failure", "#edit_server_form", (xhr, status, error) ->
    console.log 'ajax:failure'
).on("ajax:error", "#edit_server_form", (xhr, status, error) ->
    console.log 'ajax:error'
).on("ajax:complete", "#edit_server_form" ->
    console.log 'ajax:complete'
```

--

The problem you have *isn't* a lack of request, but its logging.

The "`Beginning`" message suggests that a request *is* being fired.

Because `Turbolinks` causes issues with the DOM (it refreshes the `body` without updating the JS / assets), you have to [delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30406119/1143732) from an element which is always going to remain present. We use `document`, although it's quite inefficient.

---

You'd also do well to use the following with your form:

```
<%= form_for @server, remote: true, url: servers_path, method: "get", html: { id: "edit_server_form" } do |f| %>
```